# Эластичный шрифт

Tags: css

Ситуация такова: сайт полностью резиновый, тоесть по ширине и по высоте он растягивается в независимости от размера окна. Есть блок, в котором должен быть текст и этот текст должен также растягивать по ширине и по высоте.
Грубо говоря, как будто это изображение. оно растягивается не соблюдая пропорций. можно вытянуть его на всю высоту экрана, но при этом по ширине с узить

Comment: вот такой https://youtu.be/CmcN0nwI16w нужен эффект

Comment: svg или canvas тут только помогут, если без js. Если хотите в обычном контейнере, то js + css transform scale

Comment: Спасибо за помощь! буду колдовать...